# Timestamp format for phoenix upsert into hbase?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I am writing upsert script for phoenix to make the records in hbase.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp.table (
id bigint(20),
created_at timestamp,
updated_at timestamp,
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And when I use upsert script

```
upsert into temp.table values(1000,'2014-07-30 13:33:45','2014-07-30 13:33:45');
```

I get the following error

```
Error: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. TIMESTAMP and VARCHAR for 2014-07-30 13:33:45 (state=22005,code=203)
```

And when I use

```
upsert into temp.table values(1000,13907665544,13907665544);
```

I get the error

```
Error: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. TIMESTAMP and LONG for 13907665544 (state=22005,code=203)
```

What is the other form to write upsert script when the columns has `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your query once again. you should change your query from

```
upsert into temp.test_table(1000,'2014-07-30 13:33:45','2014-07-30 13:33:45');
```

to

```
upsert into temp.test_table values (1000,'2014-07-30 13:33:45','2014-07-30 13:33:45');
```

tested on **sqlline version 1.1.8**

Also I have changed the table name from `temp.table` to `temp.test_table` as it was giving me the following error

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 604 (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting "NAME", got "table" at line 1, column 33.
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Still it's not working. There was typo in my question I forgot to write `values` before bracket.